# Divide fruits among 3 people

Tags: combinatorics

The question is how can we divide 5 intendical apples, 6 identical oranges and 4 identical pears among 3 people? 
My idea is to use combination with repetition, because we want to choose elements without specifying order. Sadly I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it if e.g. only the $5$ apples are to be divided? If there are no further conditions then you can split up in $3$ rounds of dividing the fruits.

Comment: So, any person can get anything from $0$ to all the 16 fruits?

Comment: @JimmyR. Yes I think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Calculate the product of the following values:

- The number of ways to express $5$ as a sum of $3$ non-negative integers
- The number of ways to express $6$ as a sum of $3$ non-negative integers
- The number of ways to express $4$ as a sum of $3$ non-negative integers

Comment: BTW, the order of the terms in each sum is important.

Comment: Ok so there are 8 possibilities for a first sentence am I right?

Comment: @Charllie: There are a lot more. Permute $0,0,5$. Permute $0,1,4$. Permute $0,2,3$. Permute $1,1,3$. Permute $1,2,2$. That $21$ options altogether.

Comment: @Charllie: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

According to Barak hint I want to present the answer. One more time big thanks Barak. 
Let's count this for apples. I was wrong that order not matters. Order is necessary because we are talking about dividing fruits among people and people differ from each other.

```
Apples:
0 0 5 there are 3!/2! +
1 1 3 there are 3!/2! +
4 0 1 there are 3! +
2 2 1 there are 3!/2! +
3 2 0 there are 3!
```

Sum it, then do the same thing for oranges and pears and multiply everything.

Comment: Your last senctence is not correct, it should read: ".... and multiply everything" instead of "...sum everything"!

Comment: Yeah, really sorry you got right, big thanks for your comment.